# Is this simple transaction safe from race condition?

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have a stored procedure like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE incrementSomeNum()
BEGIN
    START TRANSACTION;  # Not sure if this line is necessary.

    DECLARE a INT;
    SELECT someValue INTO a FROM someTable WHERE id = 1;
    UPDATE someTable SET someValue = a + 1 WHERE id = 1;

    COMMIT; # And this
END;
```

Now in my client I have code like this, run in threads.

```
connection = connectionPool.getConnection()
connection.query("CALL incrementSomeNum();");
connection.close();
```

Is this safe from race conditions?

(Suppose I'm using MySQL, and the table uses InnoDB engine.)

Comment: Can you be sure what default transaction isolation level is set in the database, database connection or session?

Comment: @NineBerry According to this  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html, The default isolation level for InnoDB is REPEATABLE READ. But I don't know if this matters. And if it does, what is the minimum level to make it safe, and why?

Comment: The default isolation level can be changed in the configuration of the database or by executing SQL during runtime.

Comment: If I am reading this correctly:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locking.html -- the locking level for an update is exclusive, regardless of the default isolation level.  Because your statements access the same rows in the same order, there won't be a deadlock condition where different executions are blocking different resources.  The worst you will experience is a timeout if one of your calls has to wait for too many other executions.  This is only true for as long as your app reuses the same statement.  Different statements on the same rows could cause blocking issues.

Comment: @user7396598 It's not about a deadlock. It's whether the value will be incremented by the correct amount.

Comment: Then this goes to the part of my comment about a timeout occurring.  Your locks will be acquired, field updated, lock released sequentially without fear of deadlock in this situation.  This forces your multiple threads to have their sql executed sequentially at the sql server.  Possibly resulting in a timeout if one of the calls waits too long.  To ensure all your executions actually get applied your application could catch and retry when timeouts are encountered.

Comment: This is actually a textbook example of a case where you need serializable isolation (so with default settings, your code will not be safe). Check out [InnoDB row locking - how to implement](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/15854/117531) (or similar questions) for some explanations. (Also, I assume your code is just an example, as in your specific case you can simply use `UPDATE someTable SET someValue = someValue + 1 WHERE id = 1;` to make it safe.)